# File name is too long Git in Windows 11 error

Tags: git, git-for-windows

I'm using `Git-1.9.0-preview20140217` for Windows. As I know, this release should fix the issue with too long filenames. But not for me.

Surely I'm doing something wrong, I did:

```
git config core.longpaths true 
git add . 
git commit
```

Everything went well. But when I now do a git status, I get a list of files with Filename too long, for example:

```
node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/bin-wrapper/node_modules/download/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/node_modules/combined-stream/node_modules/delayed-stream/test/integration/test-handle-source-errors.js: Filename too long
```

It is quite simple to reproduce for me: just create a Yeoman web application with the Angular generator (`yo angular`) and remove `node_modules` from the `.gitignore` file. Then repeat the aforementioned Git commands.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Don't commit your `node_modules` and you're fine. Set up a `.gitignore` that excludes it. Why would you remove it? Just have the packages file in git and fetch modules on dev machines.

Answer (score 2):

The version of Git you're using is very old.  2.38.0 was just released, and the version you're using is a preview from 2014.  It's almost certain that since that release, there have been substantial improvements to Git for Windows such that it handles long filenames better.  It is known for certain that there have been security fixes since then.

This feature is specific to Git for Windows, but I have at least seen patches from 2019 in the main tree that appear to involve it.  You're therefore better off upgrading to the latest version, and if this is still not working for you, file an issue on the Git for Windows issue tracker if one is not already present.

Comment: Archived and deprecated as well: https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases, so you can't file an issue (is it the correct repo though?).

Comment: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git is what you should be using on Windows unless you're using Cygwin or WSL.

Comment: @CodeCaster MSYS was a build tools/environment for building Git for Windows package, it's not that repo. (btw. the current set of build tools is MSYS2 if I recall well)